# Uncaught TypeError: Object .NumCon has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want run a jquery code that if number value text input was under of `7`, the result is false. but i get following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object .NumCon has no method 'apply'
     f.event.dispatch
     f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

What do i do?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FZMsP/

This is my code:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" name="user_pass" class="NumCon" id="7">
</form>

​
function NumCon() {
    var result = true;
    $(this).closest("form").find('.NumCon').each(function () {
        var size = this.value.length;
        var NumVal = $(this).attr('id');
        if (size <= NumVal) {
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        }else{
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffec");
        }
    });
}

$('.NumCon').live('keyup', NumCon());​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling your function from inside of the definition line, which is (for some reason) then interpreted as an object.

```
$('.NumCon').on('keyup', NumCon);​
```

Solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

.live has now been depreciated, seems youre now meant to use:
    $(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });

[Jquery .live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

​The solution is

`$('.NumCon').on('keyup', yourFunction(yourParameters));`

source http://api.jquery.com/on/